# safeWithdraw not working

Tags: contract-development

I'm using the crowdsale contract from the ethereum site but I have made a few changes. I added a tokenWithdraw function, if the beneficiary runs it you can withdraw a set amount of tokens from the contract. I have tested and it works fine.

However the safeWithdraw function which should do the same thing except withdraw ETH rather than the Token does not work when I run it as the beneficiary. The ETH just stays in the contract for some reason and I have no idea why.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
contract token { function transfer(address receiver, uint amount); }

contract Crowdsale {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public fundingGoal; uint public amountRaised; uint public deadline; uint public price; uint public tokenW; uint public ethW; token public tokenReward;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    bool fundingGoalReached = false;
    event GoalReached(address beneficiary, uint amountRaised);
    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);
    bool crowdsaleClosed = false;

/* data structure to hold information about campaign contributors */

/*  at initialization, setup the owner */
function Crowdsale(
    address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
    uint fundingGoalInEthers,
    uint durationInMinutes,
    token addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
) {
    beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
    fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers * 1 ether;
    deadline = now + durationInMinutes * 1 minutes;
    price = 25;
    tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
}

function () payable {
    if (crowdsaleClosed) throw;
    uint amount = msg.value;
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
    amountRaised += amount;
    tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount * price);
    FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
}

modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

function checkGoalReached() afterDeadline {
    fundingGoalReached = true;
    GoalReached(beneficiary, amountRaised);
}


function closeCrowdSale()  {
  if (beneficiary == msg.sender) {
  crowdsaleClosed = true;
  }
}

function withdrawTokens(uint tokenW) {
  if (beneficiary == msg.sender) {
    tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, tokenW);
  }
}

function safeWithdrawal(uint ethW) {
    if (beneficiary == msg.sender) {
      FundTransfer(beneficiary, ethW, false);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Who are you setting as the beneficiary of this contract? The wallet that deployed the contract? Or a separate wallet??

Comment: When using the safe withdraw function: 1) Does it have to be after the deadline?
2) What do I put in eth w?? The amount I want to send to the beneficiary?
3) Do I have to send eth as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason changing it to this worked, anyone able to advise why?

```
function safeWithdrawal(uint ethW) {
    if (beneficiary == msg.sender) {
      if (beneficiary.send(ethW)) {
            FundTransfer(beneficiary, ethW, false);
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function:

```
function safeWithdrawal(uint ethW) {
    if (beneficiary == msg.sender) {
      FundTransfer(beneficiary, ethW, false);
    }
 }
```

You are only:

1.Checking if the sender is beneficiary:

```
if (beneficiary == msg.sender) {
```

2.Publishing a `FundTransfer` event:

```
FundTransfer(beneficiary, ethW, false);
```

There is no code to perform any update on contract state or send transaction. That's why you need to add an instruction that will actually send ether:

```
beneficiary.send(ethW);
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, that makes sense now! I was just displaying the info rather than performing the actual transaction. I added a if (beneficiary.send(ethW) then publish fundtransfer event. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using the testrpc..if so, then sending eth from contracts doesn't work.  I'd give it a try on Ropsten or the mainnet and you should be good to go

Comment: no this is on the main net

Comment: for some reason I had to add this if statement to it  if (beneficiary.send(ethW))   any idea why?

Comment: beneficiary.send(ethW) sends the ether.. Before you were not sending it.